# bgStretcher not working in FireFox or Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox

Okay so I'm wrapping up a my website and I'm having issue with FireFox and Chrome.  The issue is the same for both browsers so I'm guessing it's an easy fix and I'm just being dumb.

So I'm using bgStretcher from ajaxblender.com.  Everything works wonderfully on IE9 but when I load the site on FireFox and Chrome, bgStretcher is either not loading or not loading correctly.  The background does not function as the background and the divs are pushed to the bottom and moved all out of whack.  The HTML code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    //  Initialize Backgound Stretcher     
    $('body').bgStretcher({
        images: ['images/gervais_street.jpg'],
        imageWidth: 1024, 
        imageHeight: 720, 
    });

});
```

When I comment this section out, the divs function correctly but obviously there is no background.  Can anyone see anything with this that is wrong?

Here is the code for the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>gg web design</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bgstretcher.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/gg.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bgstretcher.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<!-- from ajaxblender.com -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        //  Initialize Backgound Stretcher     
        $('body').bgStretcher({
            images: ['images/gervais_street.jpg'],
            imageWidth: 1024, 
            imageHeight: 720, 
        });

    });
</script>
<!-- end ajaxblender.com script -->

<script src="js/create_menu.js"></script>
<script>
    create_menu();
</script>

<div id="content">
    <center>
        welcome to G<span class="mirror">G</span> web design.
    </center>
</div>

<div id="picture_credit">
    gervais street bridge - photo by steve moore&nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>

<script src="js/create_footer.js"></script>
<script>
    create_footer();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I know I'm probably doing something stupid so be gentle.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I would try is swapping the order that you're loading the css. Put the bgstretcher.css call last instead of first.

Another thing to consider is using background-size:cover for modern browsers. You could put the bgstretcher calls(both js and css) in an IE conditional statement to handle the background for IE.

Here's a [good link](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) on the topic...

Comment: background-size:cover after a little fiddling worked perfectly!  Thanks Shane!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting document instead of body

```
$('document').bgStretcher({
    images: ['images/gervais_street.jpg'],
    imageWidth: 1024, 
    imageHeight: 720
});
```